# Cutting axis ticks at the correct limits when setting coord_cartesian limits on factorised continuous x

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to combine continuous and categorical data and need to factorise my continuous variable. I struggle to understand how to cut off the axis ticks on the right limits.

I understand that the x limits are based on the new factor levels, but why do the ticks extend beyond the lower limit?

**Background**: 
I'd like to combine a linear regression line on a continuous variable (with `geom_smooth`) with summarising stats on binned data of the same variable (e.g., `geom_boxplot`). I need to create a factor with all levels because otherwise those plots don't overlay. But this then creates a lot of blank space to both sides, therefore I tried to set the limits with `coord_cartesian`, which I am aware is always continuous.

```r
library(ggplot2)

foo <- data.frame(x = 20:50, y = rnorm(31))

ggplot(foo) + 
  geom_col(aes(factor(x), y)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(10,50))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `coord` systems are always continuous. `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(10,50))` tells `ggplot` do draw the axis from the 10th factor level to the 50th. You only have 31 factor levels, so there's a lot of blank space. What are you trying to accomplish with `coord_cartesian`? Deleting that line and using the defaults or `scale_x_discrete` is probably better.

Comment: @GregorThomas See my updated "background" in the question. Your comment does unfortunately not answer the problem with the overshooting axis ticks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `group` aesthetic to define which bar is which, rather than using a discrete scale.

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x, y)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_col(aes(group = x))
```

[image]

Comment: OK that is a great idea, thanks. It works well for my example, but I am realising now it actually does not work with the specific geom I want to use (`ggthemes::geom_tufteboxplot`)- at least for me it currently doesn't work. Guess will play around and maybe ask a follow up question. Credit to you already

Comment: @Tjebo in that case, go all discrete and give a grouping variable to the `smooth`, e.g., `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm") +
  ggthemes::geom_tufteboxplot()`